# Changing an optimisers momentum in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, momentum

I know you can change the learning rate dynamically in pytorch using schedulers. How can you do the same with momentum?

Answer (score -2):

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiplicativeLR) for Multiplicative LR in PyTorch. Basically, you wrap your scheduler around the optimizer the same way you wrap your optimizer around model params.

```
lmbda = lambda epoch: 0.95
scheduler = MultiplicativeLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lmbda)
for epoch in range(100):
    train(...)
    validate(...)
    scheduler.step()
```

Comment: How does this dynamically adjust the momentum parameter for the optimizer? It appears to only adjust the learning rate.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you specifically want momentum. You can modify the source code of the scheduler you want to use to adjust momentum. For example, here you can use code here:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#CosineAnnealingLR

and adjust momentum using group['momentum']